# Chrome / Firefox inconsistent when parent is positioned with absolute

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a map with rounded icons on it.

I'm using empty canvas elements to preserve 1:1 aspect ratio on rounded containers

When viewing in Chrome 67 everything is fine, but with Firefox 60 it does not work, aspect ratio is not preserved and icons have a content width of zero (only their padding make them visible)
It happens if parent (`.zone`) has `position:absolute`, however it work when `.zone` has `position:relative`.

I really need `position:absolute`, does somebody know why firefox does not expand width of `.item` to adjust to the canvas element ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: 0;
}

.zone {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: calc(100% / 11);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: help;
  border: 1.5px solid #0acaff;
  color: #0acaff;
}

.item canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

.square_content {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zone">
  <!-- inline style is computed -->
  <div class="item" style="left: 22.727%;top: 77.273%;">
    <canvas width="1" height="1"></canvas>
    <div class="square_content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: on the snippet you should see mostly a gray zone with a perfectly rounded icon (blue border and red background)

Comment: your zone is the parent, and no parent should have position:absolute; if it has other elements with position absolute as children. You can use another div outside zone, and give that position relative, full width and height.

Comment: Can you share a page link where you are facing this issue?

Comment: @AnilK. I'm afraid I can't, it's on a backoffice

Comment: The `.zone` element is positionned absolute because it needs to be over another element, I will share a codepen to show the setup in a few minutes

Comment: here it is: https://codepen.io/VincentCharpentier/pen/XBPGab?editors=0100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `height: calc(100% / 11);` it's value is not picking up in ***Firefox***, if you change the **`%`** to [**`vw`**](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) your code will work fine.

A sample code for you:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: 0;
}

.zone {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 4vw;
  /* or height: calc(40vw/11); */
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: help;
  border: 1.5px solid #0acaff;
  color: #0acaff;
}

.item canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

.square_content {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zone">
  <!-- inline style is computed -->
  <div class="item" style="left: 22.727%;top: 77.273%;">
    <canvas width="1" height="1"></canvas>
    <div class="square_content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*The above sample work will all browsers, Hope this was helpful for you.*

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work even with `9%` instead of `calc(100% / 11)` but worked with any `px`, `vw` or `vh` units. I guess the issue here is the order of computation performed by the browser. I'm trying to make this reusable (so finite units are not my best bet), I guess the only way to achieve this is to compute the height with javascript then ?

Comment: `vh` can be used to achieve the same result you get using `%` then what is the issue for you.!

Comment: this is just an isolated problem, in my real use case it is deep inside the dom, I'll show you with a codepen in a few minutes

Comment: this is a more contextual example: https://codepen.io/VincentCharpentier/pen/XBPGab?editors=0100

Comment: I think your answer is the best way to solve this without javascript. However I did some scripting to match perfectly cell height (instead of `height: calc((100% - 10px) / 11)`). Thanks for your help